# Voltage drops are greater than source voltage. How is it possible?

Tags: voltage, ac, phasor

[image]

This circuit was given in my textbook. The source voltage is only 10 Volts, but the individual voltage drop across resistor and inductor are 6 Volts and 8 Volts respectively, which is greater than the source voltage. How is it possible?

Is it possible in real practical circuits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the voltage across the inductor is not DC, but a sinusoidal voltage, whose *amplitude* is 8V (or maybe 8V is its RMS value, it is not clear from the context).

That voltage is not in phase with the voltage across the resistor, so they don't add in the usual (DC) way.

You should use [*phasors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) (a vector-like representation of sinusoidal AC voltages) to perform the calculation exactly (using complex numbers, for example, or a graphical representation).

In short, a sinusoidal quantity (voltage or current) is represented by a vector in the complex plane having a length which is equal to the amplitude of the quantity. The vector has its tail in the origin and it forms an angle with the positive real axis which is equal to the *phase* of the sine wave (with respect to some reference).

Usual Kirchhoff's laws holds also for phasors, but you need to use vector (or complex) addition instead of conventional real number addition.

In your circuit what you know is:

- R and L are in series, so they share the same current
- R and L are in series, so the *vector sum* of the voltages across them equals the overall voltage across the series (10V 50Hz).
- the current is in phase with the voltage across R (that's a property of resistors)
- the current has a phase lag of 90° with respect to the voltage across the inductor (that's a property of inductors)

Assuming the voltages shown in the schematic represent amplitudes and not RMS values (that's not very important since for a sine wave \$V_{amplitude} = \sqrt{2} \cdot V_{rms}\$), then you can draw a vector diagram where you have an horizontal vector (pointing right) of length 6V (the voltage across R) and a vertical vector (pointing downwards) of length 8 (the voltage across L).

Using the [vector addition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html) you find out that the voltage across the series has an amplitude which is the hypotenuse of a triangle having 6V and 8V as sides, hence:

$$
V_{across series} = \sqrt{6^2 + 8^2} = \sqrt{36 + 48} = \sqrt{100} = 10V
$$

Of course this is only the amplitude of the voltage. You can use trigonometry formulas to get the phase.

**EDIT**

This is what happens in the time domain:

[image]

the red curve is the voltage across the resistor (sine wave with 6V peak value), the blue one is the voltage across the inductor (sine wave with 8V peak value, delayed in time of a quarter of a period, which is what 90° phase lag means). If you add their value at any time, you get the green curve, which has a peak value of 10V and so it will never reach 14V.

Comment: Is it possible in real circuits. Where from that extra voltage come

Comment: Yes. It doesn't come from anywhere, the two voltages are out of phase

Comment: @ChiduruppulaSharathKumar That's not an "extra voltage". You are still assuming AC voltages add up the same way as DC voltages.

Comment: @ChiduruppulaSharathKumar the instantaneous voltage add the same, but since the two voltages are not in phase, they reach their peak value at different instants, so the resulting sum has a peak which is lower than what  you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation. So, since the voltage across resistor is 6 Volts and voltage across inductor is 8 Volts and there is a phase difference between resistor voltage and inductor voltage, it means one particular instant of time, they add and give the total voltage drop as 8+6 =14 Volts. Is it right ? And next instant of time, the total voltage changes from 14 Volts to another value. Is it right?

Comment: @ChiduruppulaSharathKumar No, they will never add up to 14V.  See my edit

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo Donati. Thank you for clear explanation. My doubt was cleared. I am not understanding this concept from past two days. But you really helped me alot. Thank you very much. One more favour , can you please draw supply voltage waveform in that diagram you posted.

Comment: Sir/madam can you please draw supply voltage waveform in the graph you posted. Please.

Comment: @ChiduruppulaSharathKumar What do you mean by "supply voltage"? There is no generator drawn in the schematic, so there's no explicit supply. If you mean that 10V/50Hz shown in the figure, that's not necessarily the supply. Anyway, I've already drawn it, it's the green waveform! If you are studying this for an university or college course, you should really review the basics, since you miss a lot.

Comment: Yes sir/madam, i am weak in some basic concepts. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Phase]

To understand what is going in this circuit consider the above picture taken from an Oscilloscope.

The red wave represents the voltage across the inductor and the blue represents the Voltage drop across the resistor.

With supply voltage of 10V-50Hz sine wave to match your example.

In this picture every square represents 5V so the blue waveform has a peak(max value) of about 5V and about 9V peak for the red(Inductor voltage) waveform.

If we simply add these two maximums together this will result in a total voltage of 14V which is above our input voltage '10V-peak'.

The key here is that the two voltages (inductor's and resistor's) are out of phase, meaning, they don't reach their 0 value or maximum value at the same time.

This is apparent from the picture above. We can see that when the red waveform is maximum the blue one is zero. And when the blue waveform is maximum the red one is zero.

Since both waveforms are out of phase you cannot simply add their peak (or rms values).

If we use this formula Vtot = sqrt((V1)^2 + (V2)^2) the result will be 10V which is the supply voltage

V1:Peak voltage across the inductor.

V2:Peak voltage across the resistor.

This strange behaviour comes from the fact that

-the current and voltage of the inductor are 90deg out of phase.

-The current through the resistor is the same current through the inductor.

-Current and voltage of the resistor are in phase 'both are zero together and 
 maximum together'.

So the voltage across the resistor and the voltage across the inductor are 90 degrees out of phase.

Comment: Can you please draw supply voltage waveform in that diagram you posted.

Comment: Sorry,but the oscilloscope has only two channels

Comment: If the input waveform was present,you will find that the 'instantanous' input voltage value will be the sum of the instantanous voltage drops across the inductor and the resistor.

Comment: Ok i understood. Thank you very much for your answer.